# Move an item of recyclerview into another recyclerview on button click on custom adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have two recycler views and both of them use the same custom adapter.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SUjT.jpg - this is how the item from the recycler view looks like

What i want to do is, whenever the "Anuleaza rezervarea" button is clicked, i want to remove the item from the current recyclerview and add it to another recycler view

How can i do that? I'll leave my custom adapter code below. I really don't understand what to write in the on click listener.

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapterRezervare extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapterRezervare.RecycleViewHolder> {
    private List<Rezervare> rezervari;
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private String numeUtilizator;
    private String status;

    private Rezervare rezervare = new Rezervare();

    private DatabaseReference reff;

    public RecyclerViewAdapterRezervare(List<Rezervare> rezervari, Context context, String numeUtilizator) {
        this.rezervari = rezervari;
        this.context = context;
        this.numeUtilizator = numeUtilizator;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecycleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rezervari_layout, parent, false);
        return new RecycleViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecycleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        rezervare = rezervari.get(position);

        holder.btn_anuleaza.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext()).setTitle("Anulare rezervare").setMessage("Sunteti sigur ca doriti anularea rezervarii?")
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.da, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            holder.btn_anuleaza.setText(R.string.anulat);
            holder.btn_anuleaza.setBackgroundColor(view.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            }
          }).setNegativeButton(R.string.nu, null).show();
          }
          });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return rezervari.size();
    }

    public static class RecycleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView tv_nume_teren;
        public TextView tv_adresa_teren;
        public TextView tv_ora;
        public TextView tv_data;
        public Button btn_anuleaza;
        public Button btn_navigheaza;

        public static boolean isCanceled;


        public RecycleViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tv_nume_teren = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_rezervare_nume_teren);
            tv_adresa_teren = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_rezervare_adresa_teren);
            btn_anuleaza = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_anuleaza);
            btn_navigheaza = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_maps);
            tv_ora = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_rezervare_ore);
            tv_data = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_rezervare_data);

            isCanceled = false;

            if(isCanceled){
                btn_anuleaza.setText(R.string.anulat);
                btn_anuleaza.setBackgroundColor(itemView.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            } else {
                btn_anuleaza.setText(R.string.anuleaza_rezervare);
                btn_anuleaza.setBackgroundColor(itemView.getResources().getColor(R.color.teal_700));
            }
        }
    }
```

When i click on the "Anuleaza rezervare" button, the two buttons become red and unclickable, and i want to transfer the item to another recycler view. How can i do that? Thank you!

Comment: when you click on the item the item is added to another recycler view list and also remove the item in the current recycler view.don't forgot to notify data set to change in adapter

Comment: but i want to move the item when i click the button on the item (just like in the image). How can i add to another list when i click the button on the item?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by calling,
`int removeIndex = 2;`
`data.remove(removeIndex);`
`adapter.notifyItemRemoved(removeIndex);`

on the first recyclerView and update the second by calling,

`String newItem = "This is a new item.";`
`int updateIndex = 3; // Your index to insert new the item`
`data.set(updateIndex, newItem);`
`adapter.notifyItemChanged(updateIndex);`

for the second recyclerView.

Comment: yes but i want to add to the second list when i click the button on the item (just like in the photo), and i want to add the same element i have deleted

Comment: Okay, then you can first save the item to be deleted in a temporary variable and then add that to the another list, using `secondList.add(tempItem);` and this will be added to the another list.

Comment: but how can i make the difference between the first recyclerview and the second one, because they both use the same custom adapter?